# Configuring Mapping of objects and its properties in XML

Tags: c#, .net, nunit-2.5

I am writing Automation test script using Nunit and Selenium, 
After completing my test case I need to verify the results by calling one service and verifing its attrobutes with source system , Source system are Testcase.xml , another web service and user information which is used to execute this test case.

Its like this. 
1. Execute the test case by using Testcase.xml and user Information by calling user source system 
2. Once test case is executed make a call to web service which is nothing but assertions to verify backend system get updated. 
3. Get the Response object and verify its values with Source (xml,User information)

Problem is I need to verify attributes of the response with different sources like My Test data (a xml file) , Another source system which is nothing but another service response objects. 
Curretnly I am having this logic in code in if else statement (hard coded) but i want to configure it

Is there any way how can i configure it in XML like 
Use x property fromsource object to verify z in the results. 
Please advice